# Cannot add texture to an Irrlicht node

Tags: irrlicht

I am trying to add a bitmap texture to my custom scene node in Irrlicht.
For that I followed one of their tutorials and ended up with this:

```
IAnimatedMesh* mesh = smgr->getMesh("mesh.3ds");
IAnimatedMeshSceneNode* node = smgr->addAnimatedMeshSceneNode( mesh );
node->setMaterialTexture( 0, driver->getTexture("texture.bmp") );
```

But at the runtime, my node is totally black.
In the console logs I can see that the image did load correctly.

What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you did not set any lighting thus the black output.
Try making your node unlightable:

```
node->setMaterialFlag(EMF_LIGHTING, false);
```